# Android Java Retrofit login with bearer token - Spring Boot Backend JWT token

Tags: android, spring-boot, oauth-2.0, jwt, bearer-token

i've seend some somehow similar but still different questions here, and sadly non of their answers worked for me.

For a project at the university i need to implement login and registration for an android app with a spring boot backend which uses JWT Token (when I use Postman it shows a bearer token with OAuth 2.0 authhorization, actually with postman everything works fine, so backend is running correctly - and Registration is working fine, but it's logic is much simpler).

Basically if someone could direct me to a good tutorial how to implement login for android to a backend which response with a bearer token i would be very very very thankful. I did search google but did never find a whole tutorial on how to implement this.

So far i got this:

the api interface:

```
public interface TheApi {

    @POST("/login")
    @FormUrlEncoded
    Call<LoginResponse> login(
            @Field("username") String username,
            @Field("password") String password);

}
```

The Main Activity with the Call:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private TextView textViewResult;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        textViewResult = findViewById(R.id.text_view_result);

        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("http://192.168.0.75:8080/")
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();

        TheApi theApi = retrofit.create(TheApi.class);

        LoginRequest loginRequest = new LoginRequest("admin@admon.com", "admin123");

        Call<LoginResponse> call = theAwesomeApi.login(loginRequest.getUsername(), loginRequest.getPassword());

        call.enqueue(new Callback<LoginResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<LoginResponse> call, Response<LoginResponse> response) {
                if (!response.isSuccessful()) {
                    textViewResult.setText("Code: " + response.body() + response.code());
                    return;
                } else {
                    textViewResult.setText("error login");
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<LoginResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                textViewResult.setText("error connection");
            }

        });
```

The LoginRequest Class:

```
public class LoginRequest {

    @Expose
    @SerializedName("username")
    private String username;

    @Expose
    @SerializedName("password")
    private String password;


    public LoginRequest(String username, String password) {
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
    }


    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

}
```

And the LoginResponse Class:

```
public class LoginResponse {

    private String authToken;


    public LoginResponse(String authToken) {
        this.authToken = authToken;
    }


    public String getAuthToken() {
        return authToken;
    }

    public void setAuthToken(String authToken) {
        this.authToken = authToken;
    }

}
```

Yes, I did not implement anything useful to save the bearer token for reuse later, but I first wanted to check if I could login somehow.

And sadly the backend responds only with a 403 error code

And the backends logs this error:

> 2020-06-30 18:56:42.618 ERROR 13141 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    >: Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception
>
> java.lang.NullPointerException: null
> at >com.theawesomelibrary.awesomebackend.security.JwtAuthenticationFilter.attemptAuthentication(Jwt>AuthenticationFilter.java:49) ~[classes/:na]

It seems like no username or password is sent, but i dont' understand what i did wrong and could not find any solution yet. Please need your help dear community.

Could some one point me the solution how to send a correct post request for login
and how to get the bearer token for later use?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check your api working fine? I tried your api with postman  and didn't get any response.

Comment: The API is working completely fine using postman,but it is on localserver

Comment: Interestingly i found many tutorials, videos on youtube,.. where the api returns a JSon body and the sometimes the token in the body sometimes in the header. But my API returns no body and the token in the header

Comment: header, response set by server not by retrofit

Comment: Ok. but i could never find a sufficient tutorial in java how to read the header of a response with retrofit2

Comment: Response< LoginResponse > login(
            @Field("username") String username,
            @Field("password") String password);

}

You can read header and body from response  now like response.getBody()